# Can't configure ZEND to work

Tags: php, zend-framework

I tried both ZF 1.12.0 and 2.0.3, then ran this [code](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/Gdata/InstallationChecker.php):

On my computer it didn't work and seemed to stuck in this line:

```
$videoEntry = $yt->newVideoEntry();
```

I know that because when I put two echos around that line, only the first got displayed.

The weird thing is that there is no such method called `newVideoEntry()` anywhere, at all.
And the most annoying thing is that it works completely fine on [phpcloud](http://rene.my.phpcloud.com/email.php), which turn out to be using ZF 1.11.11, an old version that I can't find anywhere on the internet.

I'm really lost. Any idea? Which version I should use, since they are so much different and incompatible. Any solution for that code ?

Comment: any error code or stack trace? Also check your php versions. `echo` won't work very well in debugging that code. Try `var_dump()` or `Zend_Debug::dump($var);` instead.

Comment: if you want to try ZF 1.11 you can get it http://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives

Comment: OK, I've tried Zend_Debug::dump($videoEntry), nothing got printed out because the program can't get out from the previous line.

Comment: put the dump at `$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();` see if the you tube object is present.

Comment: @RockyFord Thanks, I've just downloaded ZF 1.11.11 but the problem's still there. So it has nothing to do with the version. Anyway, this is what the Debug::dump returns: http://ideone.com/YeTPvp. $yt is indeed an instantiated object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method newVideoEntry() does not exist because it is a magical method. Zend_Gdata_App::__call takes care of that. It creates Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry and things go on.

Comment: Your answer actually makes it much clearer, as soon as I change the line `$videoEntry = $yt->newVideoEntry();` to `$videoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();`, it works as expected.

But I still need to fix that problem for the sake of rubustness. My ZF doesn't seem to invoke that magical method, why?

Comment: I see only one way to figure this out. Debug it.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the same library as phpcloud all you have to do is to pull the content of the zf library that is hosted on the php cloud server. dont remember where it is exactly but should be in a zend folder on the phpcloud server.
As for the error you get , without the exact error message it is hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: I turned on the error_reporting but nothing gets displayed. Obviously it gets stuck in there without any chance to return the error code. I replaced the newVideoEntry() with some nonsensical name like jasjasdjks() and they produced the same result!

Comment: did you turn on error reporting in your application.ini or did you set your application to development mode in your .htaccess or index.php?

Comment: The error_reporting works fine with other php files and any error before that damn line.